# Iptables forwarding all ports with certain destination ip address across network interfaces

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I have a slightly complex question about `iptables`.

So I have two network interfaces:

```
ens5
eth0
```

I want to route all incoming traffic from `eth0` that has an ip in the CIDR block (`10.0.0.0/16`) to `ens5`.

Is this possible with `iptables`? If so, what should my rules be?